# I want to view my all contact list after updated condition

Tags: arrays, dictionary, kotlin

I used map in this code to add a contact list in 1 condition i'm taking input from user and in 2 condition i asked user to edit the list and in the last i want to view my all contact list after `else if (choice == 3)` a edited value i think  `array.get` method is used in here but i don't know to how to use this method please help, Thank You

```
var array = arrayListOf<Map<String, Any>>()

if (choice == 1) {

    for (i in 1..3) {
        println("Enter Contact Name")
        var nameOne: Any = readLine().toString()
        println("Enter Contact Num")
        var contactOne = readLine()!!.toInt()
        var map = mapOf<String, Int>(("Name" to nameOne) as Pair<String, Int>)
        var mapTwo = mapOf<String, Int>(("Contact" to contactOne) as Pair<String, Int>)
        array.add(map)
        array.add(mapTwo)
    }
    println(array)
    println("If you want to restart the game press Y and press N for exit")
    var opt = readLine()
    if (opt == "Y" || opt == "y")
    {

        main(args)
    }
    else
    {
        exitProcess(0)
    }
}

else if (choice == 2) {
    println("Enter Name to edit")
    var editName = readLine().toString()
    println("Enter num to edit")
    var editNum = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var editThree = mapOf<String, Int>(("Name" to editName) as Pair<String, Int>)
    var editFour = mapOf<String, Int>(("Contact" to editNum) as Pair<String, Int>)
    array.add(editThree)
    array.add(editFour)

    println("The item is updated $array")
    println("If you want to restart the game press Y and press N for exit")
    var opt = readLine()
    if (opt == "Y" || opt == "y")
    {

        main(args)
    }
    else
    {
        exitProcess(0)
    }
}
else if (choice ==3)
{
    for (i in array)
    {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access by the keys `Name` and `Contact`

```
for (i in array)
{
    if (i.containsKey("Name") {
        println(i["Name"])
    }
    if (i.containsKey("Contact") {
        println(i["Contact"])
    }
}
```

But, as a suggestion, I would consider creating a model class to keep name and phone, and the array would have this class as its elements type. Like this:

```
data class Contact(val name: String, val phone: String) // Class that keeps name and phone

val array: MutableList<Contact> = ArrayList()

if (choice == 1) {
    println("Enter Contact Name")
    val nameOne: String= readLine().toString()
    println("Enter Contact Num")
    val phoneOne = readLine().toInt()
    val contactOne = Contact(nameOne, phoneOne)
    array.add(contactOne)
}
```

Then, on your condition 3:

```
for (contact in array) {
    println(contact.name)
    println(contact.phone)
}
```

Comment: Dear Sir you are right !! but in this case i don't want to use classes and also any type of functions is there any other array method  which i used to shows all the contact?

Comment: Try the direct access from the keys, first example of the answer.